# Featured articles after each node-teaser Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

How to add featured articles after each node-teaser in Drupal 7?
I can use a view but how to insert it after each node-teaser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the `.tpl.php` file associated with your content type (or created it) and embed a view previously created, like this:

```
print views_embed_view('MACHINE_NAME', 'DISPLAY_ID', $view_args);
```

You can do it as well writing your custom query in that tpl, it would be faster but a little less maintainable.

You can find plenty of examples of embedding views here: https://www.drupal.org/node/951442